# Python Version of WordCount is failing on Flink

Tags: python, centos, apache-flink, pyflink

On CentOS (CentOS 8.0.1905 (64bit)) I tried to run Python(3.6.8) Version of WordCount program on Flink(1.9) as described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/cli.html#job-submission-examples). I got error as below. The same environment works fine with Java version of WordCount program. What is that I am missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Error

```
$ ./bin/flink run -py examples/python/table/batch/word_count.py
Starting execution of program
org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment$ProgramAbortException
    at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:576)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:438)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:205)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1010)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1083)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1083)
```

Comment: Something to do with some environmental variable, I believe.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the information you provided does not show root cause. Generally speaking，we have two ways to run the example in Flink 1.9, one is the answer 1 provided earlier, which is to install the PyFlink from source, and the other is to download the binary package. as follows:

1. Check the Python
   python --version
   It’s better to use Python 2.7.6+ for Flink 1.9.
2. Download
   curl -O  http://mirrors.gigenet.com/apache/flink/flink-1.9.1/flink-1.9.1-bin-scala_2.11.tgz
   tar -zxvf flink-1.9.1-bin-scala_2.11.tgz
3. Config(Optional)
   vi flink-1.9.1/conf/flink-conf.yaml  -> rest.port: 4000
4. Start cluster
   cd flink-1.9.1; bin/start-cluster.sh
5. Run word count example
   ./bin/flink run -py examples/python/table/batch/word_count.py

More detail can be found here: 
https://enjoyment.cool/2020/01/19/Three-Min-Series-Run-the-Example-of-WordCount-in-PyFlink-1-9/#more

Hoping it is helpful to you!

Comment: The site you link to appears to be your own. Please review the [promotion guideline.](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jincheng Sun for your encouragement and support

I moved $FLINK_HOME/opt/python/__MACOSX to one level above. Program ran without any errors. As I am running on Linux, I do not need __MACOSX. I will simply delete it

Answer (score -1):

Before you run the test you should build the source and install the PyFlink by using pip, detail can be found here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/flinkDev/building.html#build-pyflink.

Comment: It looks more like comment then an answer. Please update your answer according to [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide

Comment: I did not install Flink from source. Instead I downloaded.  From log I could see "2020-01-17 10:39:40,271 ERROR org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonEnvUtils - Create symbol link for pyflink lib failed."  Message

I set PYTHONPATH as below
PYTHONPATH=$FLINK_HOME/opt/python
and in this directory  unzipped pyflink directory
I tried setting
PYTHONPATH=$FLINK_HOME/opt/python/pyflink error



flink/flink-python/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/client/python/PythonDriverEnvUtils.java

Comment: Please share the log file: log/flink-xxx-client-xxxdeMacBook-Pro.local.log due to the information you provided does not show root cause. Or please have look at  my answer 2 as well.

Comment: Hi, Sarma, I do not have permission to comment on your answer, so comment here on your answer "I moved $ FLINK_HOME / opt / python / __ MACOSX to one level above. Program ran without any errors. As I am running on Linux, I do not need __MACOSX. I will simply delete it " :)                                                         I'm curious why you encountered this problem. Normally you don't need to decompress any zip file, and you won't encounter `__MACOSX`.

Comment: You are correct. Do not unzip files in $FLINK_HOME/opt/python directory